# Understanding simple OR gate with feedback

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electricity

I am trying to understand a sample circuit in this explanation of an SR latch: https://youtu.be/KM0DdEaY5sY?t=102

[image: OR gate with an output linked with one of its inputs]

Let us assume that the system started in a position where all inputs and outputs are "zeros". Once we enable power on input "A", output "OUT" is powered on and fed back into the input "B". Once we remove power from input "A", the "OUT" is still powered by input "B".

I am struggling to explain this observation in more rigid terms than "zeroes and ones" of the logic gates. What exactly is happening from the physics standpoint? How can there be constant electric current after power was removed from input "A"? Is this some kind of residual current that will die out over time because of resistance in the wires? Why does it not die out immediately as there is apparently no source of electric field maintaining it?

I would appreciate any help with understanding this experiment. Thank you for your time!

Comment: There is a power supply involved, if the OR gate is an electronic TTL or CMOS component, etc.

Comment: If you want to see the electrical aspects of an OR gate, look up the spec sheet for the 74LS32, which is a (type of TTL) quad two-input positive OR gate.

Comment: Exactly.  A microchip like the 74LS32 has to be connected to power and ground to function.  The logic gates are connected to these sources internally; but these connections are not shown on a logic gate diagram because they're implicit and drawing them in would make the diagrams harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look up schematics for the logical gates.
E.g. on Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OR_gate you can find this one:

[image: Simple OR gate]

Please note that apart from the inputs (A and B), there is also power (+6V on the top) and ground (at the bottom). These connections are omitted on the logical diagrams, but are present in the actual electric circuit.

So in order to function, the gate doesn't rely on drawing much current from the inputs.

The same Wikipedia page provides an even simpler circuit:
[image]

and this one would indeed not work in the application presented in the video.